# Remove special symbol from string in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the issue to fetch the data based on title from database. In title it is showing some symbols not double quote due to this it is not working. I have used almost all function, strip tag, `str_replacr`, `preg`, `substr`. but it is not working. Please check the below string and help me how I can fix it.

```
“Generating Six-Figure Online Revenue from Strategic Recruitment Upsells”
```

I am using the following SQL query. If I remove the `"` then it works.

```
 SELECT post_id  as OrderID,`kcx_posts`.post_date as OrderDate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='job-title' THEN meta_value END) as JobTitle,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='_billing_first_name' THEN meta_value END) as   
  FirstName,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='_billing_last_name' THEN meta_value END) as 
  LastName,
 MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='_billing_company' THEN meta_value END) as Company,
 MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='_billing_email' THEN meta_value END) as Email,
 MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='_order_total' THEN meta_value END) as OrderTotal
FROM `kcx_postmeta` inner join `kcx_woocommerce_order_items` on    
`kcx_postmeta`.post_id= `kcx_woocommerce_order_items`.order_id
inner JOIN  `kcx_posts` ON  `kcx_postmeta`.post_id =  `kcx_posts`.ID  where 
`kcx_woocommerce_order_items`.order_item_name like '%“Generating Six-Figure    
 Online Revenue from Strategic Recruitment Upsells”%' and ( meta_key='job-
title' or meta_key='_billing_first_name' or meta_key='_billing_last_name' or 
meta_key='_billing_company'  or meta_key='_billing_email' or  
 meta_key='_order_total' ) Group By `kcx_posts`.ID desc
```

I am using the charset `utf-8` in site. Is there any way to remove it from the database ? there are lot of entries like this.

Comment: We need more info. What are you expecting? What are you getting instead? Etc.

Comment: I have added the sql query in question that I am using. Please check it.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis removed your query when editing your question - I suppose it was by accident. Either way, you give the query, but I need both [1) the current result], and [2) the required result] of your query.

Comment: @klaar yes it was by accident, I have put it back

Answer (score 0):

If you want only Alphanumeric Characters, here's an example:

```
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```